# using testcafé, how to be logged into multiple services the same time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, roles, testcafe

I am attempting to use testcafé to log into multiple services using testcafé's `role`-mechanism/concept. My tests need to be logged into multiple services at the same time (i.e. they don't want to switch between roles).

According to this guide (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html), it should be possible to use testcafé with multiple roles. However, my tests only manage to switch between roles (i.e. they are are **not** logged into multiple services at the same time)

Quote from above guide:

> For instance, assume that you switch to a role that logs you in on
> website A. After you switch to this role, you log in to website B in
> test code. TestCafe adds a new cookie to the role branch. If you
> switch to a different role and then back to the initial role in the
> same test run, you will be logged to both website A and B. If you
> switch to this role in a different test, you will be logged in to
> website A only.

Here are my main attempts to accomplish the above, but none of them were successful.

```
import { Role } from "testcafe";

const role1 = Role("https://some-website.org", async t => {
  await t
    .typeText("input[type=text]", "")
    .typeText("input[type=password]", "")
    .click(".button");
});

const role2 = Role("https:/another-website.org", async t => {
  await t
    .typeText("input[type=text]", "")
    .typeText("input[type=password]", "")
    .click(".button");
});


fixture `Getting Started`;

test("test 1", async t => {
  await t.useRole(role1);
  // now logged in as "role1"
  await t.useRole(role2);
  // now logged in as "role2"

  // ... but not logged in as "role1" and "role2"
});

test("test 2", async t => {
  await t
    .useRole(role1) // now logged in as "role1"
    .useRole(role2); // now logged in as "role2"

  // ... but not logged in as "role1" and "role2"
});

test("test 3", async t => {
  await t
    .useRole(role1) // now logged in as "role1"
    .useRole(role2) // now logged in as "role2"
    .useRole(role1); // now logged in as "role1"

  // ... but not logged in as "role1" and "role2"
});
```

What do I need to do to be logged into multiple services at the same time?

*testcafé version: 1.8.8*

*browser: Chrome 84.0.4147.89 / macOS 10.15.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Roles clean all associated cookies when applied, so you won't be able to accomplish this using two User Roles.

You can either create one role that performs login on both pages or use the first User Role and manually log the second user in from the test body.